# How can i exclude a special character between two elements in a class in css?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, special-characters

Html:

```
<div class="secondary">
            <div class="details-menu"> overview </div>
            <div class="details-menu"> <a href="#roles"> roles</a> </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    .details-menu::before {
        content: '\25CF';
      }

      .details-menu:first-child:before {
        display: none;
      }

 .details-menu:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
        color: darkorange ;

    }
    .details-menu a:hover{
        color:darkorange;
        
    }
```

The problem here is that the special character becomes a part of the "roles" link if the mouse points at "roles". And I don't want that. Any solutions?
Keep in mind that I can't modify the .HTML file. It has to be done only in the .css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We remove pseudo-element from the `a` tag and added it into the `.details-menu`. We also add hover effect as per your requirment.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/hsbky0tj/8/

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      .details-menu {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #000;
      }

      .details-menu::before {
        content: '\25CF';
      }

      .details-menu:first-child:before {
        display: none;
      }

      .details-menu:hover,
      .details-menu a:hover {
        color: darkorange;
      }

      .details-menu:hover::before {
        color: #000;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="secondary">
      <div class="details-menu"> overview </div>
      <div class="details-menu"> <a href="#roles"> roles</a> </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: that worked. 
But I have to add a :hover property. Something like:
```    .details-menu a:hover{
        color:darkorange;
        
    }
```

Can this be modified in the same way as the previous one? if yes, how?

Comment: Okay, we will look for that.

Comment: Do you need hover effect in "Overview" or only in "roles" link?

Comment: In both. Both will have the same effect in hover. The issue here is to not apply the effect to the special character.

Comment: We have edited the code and JS Fiddle link as per your requirement.